# How to compare two different clustering approaches?

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-medoids

I'm making a project connected with identifying the dynamics of sales. My database concerns 26 weeks (so equally in 26 time-series observations) after launching the product, 126 time-series=126 different products.

I used clustering to group products with similar dynamics of sales. I applied two different approaches to pam() = k-medoids clustering. First one groupes time-series - 3 clusters, second one groupes S-curve parameters, counted before by curve fitting to each time-series - 6 clusters.

Now I would like to compare these two methods, but have no idea how to compare the quality of two clustering methods if I have different number of clusters.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: There exist a lot of "internal clustering criterions" which, generally speaking, compare clustering solutions obtained on the same data but with different clustering methods or different number of clusters, - compare cluster articulatedness. Yet you should know that these criterions are biased: 1) each criterion tends toward a specific definition of cluster shape and density; 2) some criterions are idiosyncratic towards small number of clusters.

Comment: So far, I used silhouette measure to examine cluster accuracy. Is there any unbiased way to compare it? and is there any possibility that I could countr 'correlation' for example between cluster1_method1 and cluster4_method2 to see if two methods create similar clusters (for example it will occur that cluster1_method1 consists of cluster2_method2 and cluster4_method2). Or even is there possibility to measure the distance between medoids of different clusters from method1 and method2 to see if they are close to each other?

Comment: 1) Silhouette statistic is popular and quite good clustering criterion. Its standard formula defines cluster density as average within-cluster distance. 2) Identifying similar clusters across various solutions is a different task, it's not about "validity" (articulatedness) of clusters; use crosstabulations for that.

Comment: In addition to statistical methods, I would urge you  to look at the substantive meaning: Which clustering is more useful to you?

Comment: what does it mean 'more useful' for clustering? what's more crosstabulations say to me only, if cluster from different methods concur, thats all? Cause if I count how many time-series concur in method1_cluster1, method2_cluster one etc there is a random distribution so the only interpretation is that the methods are not similar  and we cannot see any rule in matching time series between those two methods?

Comment: Usefulness is not a statistical measure. **Evaluate within your application scenario, not on the drawing board**, that is the key message. We tend to be obsessed with optimizing mathematical quantities, but if these don't measure *usefulness* for our problem, we're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, while certainly appreciating pragmatic usefulness (I didn't mention it because the OP didn't ask), I don't see why we should be more obsessed with it then with a statistic. After all, a statistic and a usefulness are the same thing - they are both arbitrarily invited criterions to judge.

Comment: Usefulness is usually not that arbitrary. You supposedly have a real-world problem to solve. Useful is what solves the real-world problem, not a purely mathematical one.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, but here I might notice that clustering, like other data mining explorations, seldom has clear preexisting problem to solve (apart from find clusters if there are)

Comment: Indeed, it seldom as a *clear* preexisting problem definition. That is *why* you can't easily translate it into a mathematical definition such as variance, but you need to inspect the results manually (e.g. through visualization and application to the "outside the vector space" problem) to see if it got you any further, or whether you need to continue exploring your data.